# Branch over number of characters of an argument provided to a macro

Tags: macros, programming, strings, csname, branching

I currently have the following command:

```
\newcommand*{\setfontshape}[1]{\@ifnotmtarg{#1}{\csname#1shape\endcsname}}
```

that helps me produce the command: `\scshape` from text `sc`.

I would like to modify my command so that it produces the command `\scshape` from both the text `sc` and the text `scshape`. One way of doing that would be to branch on the number of characters: if it's less or equal to, add `shape` to it, otherwise take it as it is:

- `sc` -> `\scshape` (short version)
- `scshape` -> `\scshape` (full version)

Another way would be to check if the string already contains `shape` or not, and if not, add it at the end. In any case, how to modify my command so that it works with both short and full versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the word `shape` as a delimiter for an argument, and gobble extra appearance of `shape` in case you use the long form:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*\setfontshape[1]{\setfontshapeA #1shape\relax}
\def\setfontshapeA#1shape#2\relax{\csname #1shape\endcsname}

\begin{document}
    
    foo
    
    {\setfontshape{sc} hello}
    
    bar
    
    {\setfontshape{scshape} hello}
    
    baz
    
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: The command does not seem super robust, especially if it receives as an input another macro (in that case it does not seem to work). Is there a way to make it more robust?

Comment: @Vincent Noticed you've got an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the usefulness of this command. Anyway…

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\setfontshape}{m}
 {
  \IfBlankF{#1}
   {
    \vincent_shape:n { #1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \vincent_shape:n
 {
  \use:c
   {
    \str_case:nnF { #1 }
     {
      {sc}{scshape}
      {it}{itshape}
      {sl}{slshape}
     }
     { #1 }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

{\setfontshape{sc}AbcDef}
{\setfontshape{scshape}AbcDef}
{\setfontshape{it}AbcDef}
{\setfontshape{itshape}AbcDef}
{\setfontshape{sl}AbcDef}
{\setfontshape{slshape}AbcDef}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In a way that supports your idea of counting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\setfontshape}{m}
 {
  \IfBlankF{#1}
   {
    \vincent_shape:n { #1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \vincent_shape:n
 {
  \use:c { #1 \int_compare:nT { \str_count:n { #1 } < 5 } { shape } }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

{\setfontshape{sc}AbcDef}
{\setfontshape{scshape}AbcDef}
{\setfontshape{it}AbcDef}
{\setfontshape{itshape}AbcDef}
{\setfontshape{sl}AbcDef}
{\setfontshape{slshape}AbcDef}
{\setfontshape{sc}\setfontshape{sl}AbcDef}

\end{document}
```

Likely, it should be

```
\cs_if_exist_use:cF { #1 \int_compare:nT { \str_count:n { #1 } < 5 } { shape } } { \ERROR }
```

so if you do a mistake you're told about it.

Answer (score 0):

An approach using `l3regex` (testing whether the argument ends with "shape"):

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\setfontshape}{ m }{
    \tl_if_novalue:nF { #1 } {
        \regex_match:nnTF { shape\Z } { #1 } {
            \cs:w #1 \cs_end:
        }{
            \cs:w #1 shape \cs_end:
        }
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

foo

{\setfontshape{sc} hello}

bar

{\setfontshape{scshape} hello}

baz

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Or, simpler even: If you always need the first two letters of the argument only, just grab these and discard the rest:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\setfontshape}{ m }{
    \tl_if_novalue:nF { #1 } {
        \cs:w \str_range:nnn { #1 } { 1 } { 2 } \cs_end:
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

foo

{\setfontshape{sc} hello}

bar

{\setfontshape{scshape} hello}

baz

\end{document}
```

Same output as above.