# Command gobbling extra letters not working when passed another command

Tags: macros, expansion, expandafter

[On another topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/695577/4427), I was given the following command as an answer: it takes either a two letter font shape (`sc`, `it`...) or a full version (`scshape`, `itshape`...) to set the corresponding font shape.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*\setfontshape[1]{\setfontshapeA #1shape\relax}
\def\setfontshapeA#1shape#2\relax{\csname #1shape\endcsname}

\begin{document}
{\setfontshape{sc} hello}
{\setfontshape{scshape} hello}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that the command breaks when passed another macro

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*\setfontshape[1]{\setfontshapeA #1shape\relax}
\def\setfontshapeA#1shape#2\relax{\csname #1shape\endcsname}

\newcommand{\myshapeshort}{sc}
\newcommand{\myshapefull}{scshape}

\begin{document}
{\setfontshape{\myshapeshort} hello}  % Works
{\setfontshape{\myshapefull} hello}   % Does not work
\end{document}
```

Would there be a way to make the command more robust, and make it work in any case (even a command, calling a command, calling a command... and recursively)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trouble, as you tagged yourself `:-)`, is expansion. When you pass a macro to `\setfontshape`

```
\setfontshape{\foo}
```

this expands to

```
\setfontshapeA\foo shape\relax
```

Now the expansion of `\setfontshapeA` does *not* expand the macro `\foo` itself, but just returns

```
\csname\foo shape\endcsname
```

If `\foo` contains only `sc` then it works, otherwise not.

You must delay the expansion of `\setfontshapeA`. As long as the argument you pass to `\setfontshape` is at most single macro, then a simple

```
\newcommand*\setfontshape[1]{\expandafter\setfontshapeA #1shape\relax}
```

might do the trick. However, if you concoct perverse situations like

```
\def\foo{scsh}
\def\baz{ape}
\setfontshape{\foo\baz}
```

then you need to fully expand the argument first. You can do it with

```
\newcommand*\setfontshape[1]{\expandafter\setfontshapeA\expanded{#1}shape\relax}
```

or

```
\newcommand*\setfontshape[1]{\edef\next{#1shape}\expandafter\setfontshapeA\next\relax}
```

The former needs a relatively recent pdfTeX (2018), while the latter is pure Knuth-TeX.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the first version is by itself expandable, while the second one is not.

Comment: Well, the latter also isn't _pure Knuth-TeX_ as it has `\newcommand` :-)

Comment: @Niranjan With Knuth-TeX I mean the engine, not plain TeX. So in a sense... `:-)`

Answer (score 2):

Expansion issue. With my solution it's just defining a suitable variant.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\setfontshape}{m}
 {
  \IfBlankF{#1}
   {
    \vincent_shape:e { #1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \vincent_shape:n
 {
  \use:c { #1 \int_compare:nT { \str_count:n { #1 } < 5 } { shape } }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \vincent_shape:n { e }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\myshapeshort}{sc}
\newcommand{\myshapefull}{scshape}

\begin{document}

{\setfontshape{sc}AbcDef}
{\setfontshape{scshape}AbcDef}
{\setfontshape{it}AbcDef}
{\setfontshape{itshape}AbcDef}
{\setfontshape{sl}AbcDef}
{\setfontshape{slshape}AbcDef}
{\setfontshape{sc}\setfontshape{sl}AbcDef}

{\setfontshape{\myshapeshort} hello}  % Works
{\setfontshape{\myshapefull} hello}   % Works

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you like code for Knuth-TeX-engines, you can nest `\csname`-expansion for having stuff expanded via inner `\csname..\endcsname` before driving stringification and removal of "shape" via outer `\csname..\endcsname`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\csname @ifdefinable\endcsname\MyRemoveXYAndshapeAndBeyond{%
  \edef\MyRemoveXYAndshapeAndBeyond{%
    \long\def\noexpand\MyRemoveXYAndshapeAndBeyond
    ##1\string X\string Y##2\string s\string
    h\string a\string p\string e##3\relax{##2}%
  }%
  \MyRemoveXYAndshapeAndBeyond
}

\newcommand\setfontshape[1]{%
  \csname
    \expandafter\expandafter
    \expandafter            \MyRemoveXYAndshapeAndBeyond
    \expandafter\string
    \csname XY#1shape\endcsname\relax
    shape%
  \endcsname
}

\newcommand{\myshapeshort}{sc}
\newcommand{\myshapefull}{scshape}

\begin{document}
{\setfontshape{sc} hello}
{\setfontshape{scshape} hello}
{\setfontshape{\myshapeshort} hello}  % Works
{\setfontshape{\myshapefull} hello}   % Works
{\setfontshape{\myshapefull this is a secret message} hello}   % Works
\end{document}
```

In case with the TeX-engine in use `\expanded` and `\unexpanded` are available and you wish to prevent weird "missing \endcsname"-errors with some mean user-input, you can do:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\expanded{%
  \long\def\noexpand\MyRemoveshapeAndBeyond
  #1\string s\string h\string a\string p\string e%
}%
#2\relax{#1}

\newcommand\setfontshape[1]{%
  \csname
    \expandafter\MyRemoveshapeAndBeyond
    \detokenize\expanded{{#1shape}}\relax
    shape%
  \endcsname
}

\newcommand{\myshapeshort}{sc}
\newcommand{\myshapefull}{scshape}

\begin{document}
{\setfontshape{sc} hello}
{\setfontshape{scshape} hello}
{\setfontshape{\myshapeshort} hello}  % Works
{\setfontshape{\myshapefull} hello}   % Works
{\setfontshape{\myshapefull this is a secret message} hello}   % Works
\end{document}
```

You raised the question:

> Would there be a way to make the command more robust, and make it work
> in any case (even a command, calling a command, calling a command...
> and recursively)?

Calling commands implies attempts at successfully carrying out algorithms.
In your situation "successfully carrying out an algorithm" beneath other things implies that the algorithm in question

- may only deliver tokens which are suitable for forming a command name. This requirement implies that the carrying-out of the algorithm may be driven only by expansion.
- may not terminate due to having created a situation where aborting and providing error-message or the like is needed.
- should terminate at all at some point.

I think it is hard to implement a check for finding out for arbitrary macro arguments, whether a macro-based mechanism with initially a specific set of macro arguments yields an algorithm which fulfills these requirements and - if not - somehow defusing/neutralizing the situation.